# Good (and Bikini) beaches in Turkey (including Izmir and Antalya)?

Tags: turkey, beaches, mediterranean

Please don't get me wrong! I know where Turkey is and I have been to Istanbul 3 times and Ankara 2 times. All I know is that Istanbul is a prime destination for tourists going to Turkey. However, I have never been to Izmir or Antalya. Last time I remember, nobody bothered to mention any beach in Istanbul, so I assumed that there is none. I am pretty certain that Antalya and Izmir do have them.

**ACTUAL QUESTION**

Turkey is apparently partly conservative about women-men appearance and I am not sure if Izmir and Antalya are amongst the conservative places. I know that my girlfriend would possibly love to get a suntan on a hot beach near the Mediterranean.  Turkey seems to be the closest option for us at the moment. However, we do not know if there are any bikini-friendly beaches. This brings up the following question:

Is there any bikini friendly beach in Turkey (including Izmir and Antalya)?

P.S. I don't want to rely on general google things as those are sometimes inaccurate (I experienced in my Morocco trip). Pardon my ignorance if I ditched google and come to you for an answer.

Comment: 12 years ago I have been to Bodrum (in between Izmir and Antalya), and there was no (enforced) restriction on wearing a bikini.
It would maybe be better to split this question in two: 1) asking about bikini friendly beaches 2) asking about any beach at all in Istanbul. This helps to keep Travel.SE clear and organised.

Comment: @BartArondson      Just did an edit to the post separating question.

Comment: @hagubear Welcome! What Bar meant was to have each question as a separate post.  Our [help] indicates this is preferable, and indeed you are likely to get close votes on this question if it has multiple questions in it.

Comment: @MarkMayo       Apologies! I think I got it sorted out now. This question should be sufficient to answer my query :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being a Turk and living in İzmir, yes nearly all beaches in Turkey are bikini friendly. In fact, Antalya attracts millions of foreign tourists every year, mostly Russians. You will have no problems about using any kind of swim suits. You can even find topless suntan girls (generally foreigners).

For recommendations, Antalya is a better choice for it has many beaches and have too much foreign tourists and have a better climate for suntaning. In the following map, there are a lot of beaches who will satisfy your needs in Marmaris through Antalya. Beaches near Antalya is more popular through foreigners.

[image: Seasides of Turkey]
<sub>(source: [marmaris.org](http://www.marmaris.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/turkey-map.jpg))</sub>